# How to use vue-i18n with Vuetify 3 inside Singlefile components?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite, vue-i18n

For the sake of reproduction purposes I will try to describe what I've done:

- Based on the [Vuetify installation docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#installation) I created a new project via `npm create vuetify`
- Based on the [Vuetify i18n docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#vue-i18n) I installed the package `vue-i18n` and changed the plugin setup to

.

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { createVueI18nAdapter } from 'vuetify/locale/adapters/vue-i18n'
import { createI18n, useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const messages = { en: { title: "title | en" }, de: { title: "Titel | de" }}

const i18n = new createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages,
})

export default createVuetify({
  locale: {
    adapter: createVueI18nAdapter({ i18n, useI18n })
  }
})
```

- For testing purposes I changed the content of *App.vue* to

.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useLocale } from 'vuetify'

const { t, current } = useLocale()

setTimeout(() => {
  current.value = 'de';
}, 3000);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>content:</div>
    <div>{{ t('title') }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This works as expected!

- Instead of managing the messages in a large object I would like to move them to their components as described in [the vue-i18n docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/sfc.html#basic-usage). I completely removed the `messages` field from the `i18n` variable ( because I don't need the messages object anymore ) and added the following to *App.vue*

.

```
<i18n>
  {
    "en": {
      "title": "title | en"
    },
    "de": {
      "title": "Titel | de"
    }
  }
</i18n>
```

- Since this doesn't work out of the box I installed the package `@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n` the from [these docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/sfc.html#bundling-with-vite) , updated the package `@vitejs/plugin-vue` to version 3.2.0. and modified the *vite.config.ts* file to use the plugin

.

```
VueI18nPlugin({
  include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/**'),
}),
```

Unfortunately I don't know the correct path to use... For now the app does not render the message

[image]

Does someone know what's wrong or missing?

Comment: What is the version of vue?

Comment: @NehaSoni I'm using the latest version, but I tried v3.2.45

Comment: Did you try like this- https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/sfc.html#define-locale-messages-for-global-scope

Comment: @NehaSoni yes, please see this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615509/how-to-use-vue-i18n-with-vuetify-3-inside-singlefile-components#comment131745210_74636754

Answer (score 3):

First off, not entirely sure what the point or benefits are from using the vuetify i18n. Unless someone corrects me on it, you should probably just ignore it. Also, I'm going to assume Vue3, Vite and Typescript, and that you want static locale files (the translations). I use pnpm, but that's very simple to change to yarn or npm.

**Installation**

```
pnpm add vue-i18n@9
pnpm add @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n -D
```

---

**vite.config.ts** (import)

```
// I18n
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
```

**vite.config.ts** (plugin section)

I have my project setup so that the `locales` folder is in the `src` folder.
Add this to the plugins array:

```
VueI18nPlugin({
  // locale messages resource pre-compile option
  include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/locales/*.yml'),
}),
```

---

**i18n.ts** (new file)

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/messages'

export default createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'nl',
    messages
})
```

---

**index.ts** (add to the imports)

```
import i18n from './i18n'
```

**index.ts** (registerPlugins)

To the registerPlugins function you add the `.use(i18n)` and put a reference to it on the globalProperties (but I'm not 100% sure that this is good practice). It will look something like this, depending on the plugins that you use.

```
export function registerPlugins (app: App) {
    loadFonts()
    app
        .use(vuetify)
        .use(router)
        .use(pinia)
        .use(i18n)

    app.config.globalProperties.$t = i18n.global.t
}
```

---

**src/locales**
The locales folder contains YAML files of the translations. For example, two files called `en.yml` and `nl.yml` and contain a YAML structure like this:

```
button:
  login: Log in
  logout: Log off
auth:
  logged-in-as: Logged in as {name}.
  authenticated: Logged in
about:
  title: About page
```

The nl.yaml file follows the same structure but has the translation for dutch.

---

**MyComponent.vue**

To use the translations in a component, you this in your setup:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
    const { t } = useI18n()
</script>
```

And you can now use the translations in your template (example):

```
<template>
    <div v-if="isAuthenticated">
        {{ t('auth.logged-in-as', {name: user.given_name}) }}
    </div>
</template>
```

---

I had just started integrating i18n, and this seems to be a good setup. I see a somewhat similar (but not exactly) setup in the Vitesse template by Antfu. I can't promise that this is the best setup, as I've not figured that out yet, but it's probably a good start. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

From the vuetify docs:

> The Vuetify locale service only provides a basic translation function t, and should really only be used for internal or custom Vuetify components. It is recommended that you use a proper i18n library such as vue-i18n in your own application. Vuetify does provide support for integrating with other libraries.

so instead of using vuetify's `t` you should use:

```
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const { t } = useI18n;
```

Comment: When calling `const { t } = useI18n();` I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Need to install with 'app.use' function` but I'm already embedding it inside the Vuetify plugin?